# How to Move folder using REST API

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-rest-api

I am trying to Move folder to different location within Document library using REST API. **What i have done is:-** I have created SharePoint add-in through which i want to move folder from one location to another location in SharePoint Document Library.

Is there any method similar to "moveto()" method Specified [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn450841.aspx#bk_FileMoveTo) for moving folder or any other way to do the same using REST API.

thanks in advance

Comment: I haven't had much luck moving a folder in the past, but is there any reason you wouldn't just create a new folder instead?

Comment: Actually that folder contain files, So if I create new folder I have to re-upload all files into that folder, which will require more time.

Comment: Ah yeah i see. To be honest I don't think you can move folders including content though.

Comment: Manually we can do that, So there should exist some API to do the same.

Comment: are you ok with jsom to move folder/files

Comment: I agree it "should" - however theres several cases where it not the actual case. But i'll follow this topic to see if you might find a solution :)

Comment: yeah @Sunil sahu, I Just need a Solution in any way. It should work with sharepoint hosted add-in

Comment: yeah hope so :) @MortenK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use SP.MoveCopyUtil.moveFolder method to move the specified folder to the destination.

Example code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function moveFolder(){
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function(){
        var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        SP.MoveCopyUtil.moveFolder(context,"https://mytestsite.sharepoint.com/Shared%20Documents/Folder1/Folder2/Active/02_NamedFolder","https://mytestsite.sharepoint.com/Shared%20Documents/Folder1/Folder2/Inactive/02_NamedFolder");
        context.executeQueryAsync(function(){
            alert("success.");
        },function(sender, args){
             alert('request failed ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace()); 
        });
    }, "sp.js");
}
</script>
<input type='button' onclick="moveFolder()" value="Move Folder"/>
```

Reference: [How to use SP.MoveCopyUtil to copy (or move) files (or folders)](https://collab365.community/sp2016-o365-sp-movecopyutil-javascript-copy-move-files-and-folder/)

Comment: I am getting Following Error:- request failed The Destination file already exist 
                                                undefined

Comment: What i am trying to do is Moving "https://myTestSite.sharepoint.com/Shared%20Documents/Folder1/Folder2/Active/02_NamedFolder" into "https://myTestSite.sharepoint.com/Shared%20Documents/Folder1/Folder2/Inactive" folder So my method call is:- SP.MoveCopyUtil.moveFolder(context,"https://myTestSite.sharepoint.com/Shared%20Documents/Folder1/Folder2/Active/02_NamedFolder","https://myTestSite.sharepoint.com/Shared%20Documents/Folder1/Folder2/Inactive");  Where I am getting Wrong?

Comment: Change mytestsite.sharepoint.com/Shared%20Documents/Folder1/Folder2/Inactive to mytestsite.sharepoint.com/Shared%20Documents/Folder1/Folder2/Inactive/02_NamedFolder. I modify the code in the reply.

Comment: --> I am getting the following error if folder is already exist :-  "ErrorMessage: The destination file already exists. " . I want to be override new folder on the existing folder.

Comment: You can check if the folder exists first follow the article https://yieldreturnpost.wordpress.com/2015/08/25/how-to-check-with-sharepoint-jsom-if-file-or-folder-exists/

Comment: there is any method to be direct override new folder with old one. Using the above article I want to test folder is exists and if exists delete that and copy/move new one.